# CustomFormatter for logrus in Golang to display filename and line number

Tags: go

I am using **github.com/sirupsen/logrus** for logging in my golang scripts, however I want to get the filename and the line number which is logging the message. I am able to get that using the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strings"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func GetLogger() (*logrus.Logger, *os.File) {
    log := logrus.New()
    log.SetReportCaller(true)

    file, err := os.OpenFile("info.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Out = file
    log.Formatter = &logrus.TextFormatter{
        CallerPrettyfier: func(f *runtime.Frame) (string, string) {
            repopath := fmt.Sprintf("%s/src/github.com/bob", os.Getenv("GOPATH"))
            filename := strings.Replace(f.File, repopath, "", -1)
            return fmt.Sprintf("%s()", f.Function), fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", filename, f.Line)
        },
    }

    return log, file
}
```

However this gives log in the below format:

`time="2020-04-02T11:43:19+05:30" level=info msg=Hello func="main.main()" file="D:/.../main.go:13"`

But I want the log in format as below:

`Apr 02 00:00:00 INFO main.go:20 : Hello this is a log line`

How can a custom formatter be written to get this?

Answer (score 17):

This option is included in the library itself since the end of 2018.

Just set 'SetReportCaller' to true.

Here's an example:

```
package main

import (
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    // Add this line for logging filename and line number!
    log.SetReportCaller(true)

    log.Println("hello world")
}
```

The output:

```
INFO[0000]/home/trex/go/src/awesomeProject/main.go:11 main.main() hello world
```

Comment: How can I print the file path only from the repository root instead of printing the full path? Thx.

Answer (score 6):

FYI

```
log.SetReportCaller(true)
log.SetFormatter(&log.JSONFormatter{                                             
     CallerPrettyfier: func(frame *runtime.Frame) (function string, file string) {                                                     
        fileName := path.Base(frame.File) + ":" + strconv.Itoa(frame.Line)       
        //return frame.Function, fileName                                        
        return "", fileName                                                      
     },                                                                           
})
```

output：

```
{"file":"inspParse.go:290","level":"info","msg":"(3, 24), ","time":"2021-08-30T16:41:38+08:00"}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: logrus doc link: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#TextFormatter

Answer (score 2):

you can take advantage of codes below

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type MyFormatter struct {}
var levelList = [] string{
    "PANIC",
    "FATAL",
    "ERROR",
    "WARN",
    "INFO",
    "DEBUG",
    "TRACE",
}
func (mf *MyFormatter) Format(entry *logrus.Entry) ([]byte, error){
    var b *bytes.Buffer
    if entry.Buffer != nil {
        b = entry.Buffer
    } else {
        b = &bytes.Buffer{}
    }
    level := levelList[int(entry.Level)]
    strList := strings.Split(entry.Caller.File, "/")
    fileName := strList[len(strList)-1]
    b.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s - %s - [line:%d] - %s - %s\n",
        entry.Time.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05,678"), fileName,
        entry.Caller.Line, level, entry.Message))
    return b.Bytes(), nil
}

func MakeLogger(filename string, display bool) *logrus.Logger {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    logger := logrus.New()
    if display {
        logger.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f))
    } else {
        logger.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(f))
    }
    logger.SetReportCaller(true)
    logger.SetFormatter(&MyFormatter{})
    return logger
}


func main()  {
    logger := MakeLogger("/tmp/test.log", true)
    logger.Info("hello world!")
}
```

Result:
/tmp/test.log

2021-11-24 00:49:10,678 - main.go - [line:58] - INFO - hello world!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The package you're using `github.com/sirupsen/logrus` produces structured log output: that is key/value pairs. It looks like you want just a plain text logger.

The standard logger `import "log"`, produces output quite like what you want: `log.New(out, "INFO", .Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)`. (See https://play.golang.org/p/LKitIwjPuVH on the playground)

Here's example output:

```
INFO 2009/11/10 23:00:00 prog.go:10: hello
```

In go1.14, the extra flag `log.Lmsgprefix` moves the `INFO` to before the message, if that's preferable (and you can wait).

If the standard library logger doesn't do what you want (and you're not prepared to live with it), why not just copy it and edit it, essentially making your own log package? It's around 400 lines of straightforward code, and by the time you remove the parts you don't want, it'll be a lot less.

The source is here: https://golang.org/src/log/log.go

Answer (score 0):

Showing file, function name, and line number with logrus:

```
func Error(err error, msg ...interface{}) {
    if pc, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(1); ok {
        file = file[strings.LastIndex(file, "/")+1:]
        funcName := runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name()
        logrus.WithFields(
            logrus.Fields{
                "err": err,
                "src": fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s:%d", file, funcName, line),
            }).Error(msg...)
    }
}
```

Call this in every log event.